# IndexError: index 15 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 15

Tags: deep-learning, feature-extraction, feature-selection, lime, xai

Hello I am trying to incorporate LIME and GradCAM for my code that trains a deep learning model using Keras. A lot of this code if old and taken from a github repository for some research I am doing. Due to this, many of the libraries are outdated. Here are the library versions that I installed:

> keras==2.11.0
> matplotlib==3.5.2
> numpy==1.21.6
> pandas==1.4.4
> scikit-learn==1.0.2
> scipy==1.9.1
> tensorboard==2.11.2
> tensorflow==2.11.0
> protobuf==3.19.6

Additionally I am using python version 3.9.9. So I am trying to incorporate LIME for feature visualization and GradCAM for model visualization. I am using these 2 options because chatGPT said these are good options for feature and model visualization. I downloaded the latest version of LIME by the way so that could be the cause of my issue, but I have no clue since I have never used any of these technologies.
Here is the code:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import sys
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.utils import class_weight

stderr = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')
from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
sys.stderr = stderr

import numpy as np
import sys
import csv
import tf_explain
import lime
from lime import lime_tabular
#import tensorflow as tf
#from tensorflow import keras
from tf_explain.core.grad_cam import GradCAM

print("Hello")

try:
    import tensorflow as tf
    tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)
except Exception as e:
    pass


def get_df_values(type, time_window, df_values0):
    if type == 'gru':
        if time_window == 12:
            df_values = df_values0[:,
                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 11, 13, 7, 8, 15, 18, 21, 6, 9, 10, 17, 5, 16, 4, 12, 19, 20, 14]]  # 12   GRU
        elif time_window == 24:
            df_values = df_values0[:,
                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 11, 13, 15, 5, 20, 9, 21, 7, 8, 6, 17, 18, 10, 14, 4, 12, 16, 19]]  # 24   GRU
        elif time_window == 36:
            df_values = df_values0[:,
                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 11, 5, 13, 20, 9, 21, 15, 8, 7, 4, 6, 14, 12, 17, 10, 18, 16, 19]]  # 36   GRU
        elif time_window == 48:
            df_values = df_values0[:,
                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 11, 5, 13, 20, 9, 14, 8, 7, 21, 6, 4, 15, 12, 17, 16, 10, 18, 19]]  # 48   GRU
        elif time_window == 60:
            df_values = df_values0[:,
                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 11, 5, 13, 20, 7, 15, 8, 14, 6, 21, 4, 9, 12, 10, 19, 18, 16, 17]]  # 60   GRU
    elif type == 'lstm':
        if time_window == 12:
            df_values = df_values0[:,
                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 11, 13, 20, 7, 15, 8, 21, 6, 18, 5, 10, 9, 17, 16, 19, 12, 14, 4]]  # 12   LSTM
        elif time_window == 24:
            df_values = df_values0[:,
                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 20, 11, 13, 9, 15, 14, 8, 7, 5, 21, 6, 17, 18, 10, 12, 16, 4, 19]]  # 24   LSTM
        elif time_window == 36:
            df_values = df_values0[:,
                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 11, 20, 13, 5, 14, 8, 15, 7, 9, 21, 6, 4, 12, 17, 18, 10, 16, 19]]  # 36   LSTM
        elif time_window == 48:
            df_values = df_values0[:,
                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 11, 5, 20, 13, 9, 14, 7, 15, 8, 6, 4, 21, 12, 17, 18, 16, 10, 19]]  # 48   LSTM
        elif time_window == 60:
            df_values = df_values0[:,
                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 11, 5, 13, 20, 7, 15, 8, 14, 6, 21, 4, 9, 12, 10, 19, 18, 16, 17]]  # 60   LSTM
        
        
    return df_values

def load_data(datafile, series_len, start_feature, n_features, mask_value, type, time_window):
    df = pd.read_csv(datafile, header=None)
    df_values0 = df.values
    df_values = get_df_values(type, time_window, df_values0)
    X = []
    y = []
    tmp = []
    for k in range(start_feature, start_feature + n_features):
        tmp.append(mask_value)
    n_neg = 0
    n_pos = 0
    for idx in range(0, len(df_values)):
        each_series_data = []
        row = df_values[idx]
        label = row[0]
        if label == 'padding':
            continue
        has_zero_record = False
        # if one of the physical feature values is missing, then discard it.
        for k in range(start_feature, start_feature + n_features):
            if float(row[k]) == 0.0:
                has_zero_record = True
                break

        if has_zero_record is False:
            cur_harp_num = int(row[3])
            each_series_data.append(row[start_feature:start_feature + n_features].tolist())
            itr_idx = idx - 1
            while itr_idx >= 0 and len(each_series_data) < series_len:
                prev_row = df_values[itr_idx]
                prev_harp_num = int(prev_row[3])
                if prev_harp_num != cur_harp_num:
                    break
                has_zero_record_tmp = False
                for k in range(start_feature, start_feature + n_features):
                    if float(prev_row[k]) == 0.0:
                        has_zero_record_tmp = True
                        break
                if float(prev_row[-5]) >= 3500 or float(prev_row[-4]) >= 65536 or \
                        abs(float(prev_row[-1]) - float(prev_row[-2])) > 70:
                    has_zero_record_tmp = True

                if len(each_series_data) < series_len and has_zero_record_tmp is True:
                    each_series_data.insert(0, tmp)

                if len(each_series_data) < series_len and has_zero_record_tmp is False:
                    each_series_data.insert(0, prev_row[start_feature:start_feature + n_features].tolist())
                itr_idx -= 1

            while len(each_series_data) > 0 and len(each_series_data) < series_len:
                each_series_data.insert(0, tmp)

            if (label == 'N' or label == 'P') and len(each_series_data) > 0:
                X.append(np.array(each_series_data).reshape(series_len, n_features).tolist())
                if label == 'N':
                    y.append(0)
                    n_neg += 1
                elif label == 'P':
                    y.append(1)
                    n_pos += 1
    X_arr = np.array(X)
    y_arr = np.array(y)
    nb = n_neg + n_pos
    return X_arr, y_arr, nb


def attention_3d_block(hidden_states, series_len):
    hidden_size = int(hidden_states.shape[2])
    hidden_states_t = Permute((2, 1), name='attention_input_t')(hidden_states)
    hidden_states_t = Reshape((hidden_size, series_len), name='attention_input_reshape')(hidden_states_t)
    score_first_part = Dense(series_len, use_bias=False, name='attention_score_vec')(hidden_states_t)
    score_first_part_t = Permute((2, 1), name='attention_score_vec_t')(score_first_part)
    h_t = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, -1], output_shape=(hidden_size, 1), name='last_hidden_state')(hidden_states_t)
    score = dot([score_first_part_t, h_t], [2, 1], name='attention_score')
    attention_weights = Activation('softmax', name='attention_weight')(score)
    context_vector = dot([hidden_states_t, attention_weights], [2, 1], name='context_vector')
    context_vector = Reshape((hidden_size,))(context_vector)
    h_t = Reshape((hidden_size,))(h_t)
    pre_activation = concatenate([context_vector, h_t], name='attention_output')
    attention_vector = Dense(hidden_size, use_bias=False, activation='tanh', name='attention_vector')(pre_activation)
    return attention_vector


def lstm(n_features, series_len):
    inputs = Input(shape=(series_len, n_features,))
    lstm_out = LSTM(10, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.3)(inputs)
    attention_mul = attention_3d_block(lstm_out, series_len)
    layer1 = Dense(100, activation='relu')(attention_mul)
    layer1 = Dropout(0.25)(layer1)
    output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001))(layer1)
    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=output)
    return model


def gru(n_features, series_len):
    inputs = Input(shape=(series_len, n_features,))
    gru_out = GRU(10, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.3)(inputs)
    attention_mul = attention_3d_block(gru_out, series_len)
    layer1 = Dense(100, activation='relu')(attention_mul)
    layer1 = Dropout(0.25)(layer1)
    output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001))(layer1)
    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=output)
    return model

def output_result(test_data_file, result_file, type, time_window, start_feature, n_features, thresh):
    df = pd.read_csv(test_data_file, header=None)
    df_values0 = df.values
    df_values = get_df_values(type, time_window, df_values0)
    with open(result_file, 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as result_csv:
        w = csv.writer(result_csv)
        w.writerow(['Predicted Label', 'Label', 'Timestamp', 'NOAA AR NUM', 'HARP NUM',
                      'TOTUSJH', 'TOTPOT', 'TOTUSJZ', 'ABSNJZH', 'SAVNCPP', 'USFLUX', 'AREA_ACR',
                      'MEANPOT', 'R_VALUE', 'SHRGT45', 'MEANGAM', 'MEANJZH', 'MEANGBT', 'MEANGBZ',
                      'MEANJZD', 'MEANGBH', 'MEANSHR', 'MEANALP'])
        idx = 0
        for i in range(len(df_values)):
            line = df_values[i].tolist()
            if line[0] == 'padding' or float(line[-5]) >= 3500 or float(line[-4]) >= 65536 \
                    or abs(float(line[-1]) - float(line[-2])) > 70:
                continue
            has_zero_record = False
            # if one of the physical feature values is missing, then discard it.
            for k in range(start_feature, start_feature + n_features):
                if float(line[k]) == 0.0:
                    has_zero_record = True
                    break
            if has_zero_record:
                continue
            if prob[idx] >= thresh:
                line.insert(0, 'P')
            else:
                line.insert(0, 'N')
            idx += 1
            w.writerow(line)


def get_n_features_thresh(type, time_window):
    n_features = 0
    thresh = 0
    if type == 'gru':
        if time_window == 12:
            n_features = 16
            thresh = 0.45
        elif time_window == 24:
            n_features = 12
            thresh = 0.4
        elif time_window == 36:
            n_features = 9
            thresh = 0.45
        elif time_window == 48:
            n_features = 14
            thresh = 0.45
        elif time_window == 60:
            n_features = 5
            thresh = 0.5
    elif type == 'lstm':
        if time_window == 12:
            n_features = 15
            thresh = 0.4
        elif time_window == 24:
            n_features = 12
            thresh = 0.45
        elif time_window == 36:
            n_features = 8
            thresh = 0.45
        elif time_window == 48:
            n_features = 15
            thresh = 0.45
        elif time_window == 60:
            n_features = 6
            thresh = 0.5
    return n_features, thresh


if __name__ == '__main__':
    type = sys.argv[1]
    time_window = int(sys.argv[2])
    train_again = int(sys.argv[3])
    train_data_file = './normalized_training_' + str(time_window) + '.csv'
    test_data_file = './normalized_testing_' + str(time_window) + '.csv'
    result_file = './' + type + '-' + str(time_window) + '-output.csv'
    model_file = './' + type + '-' + str(time_window) + '-model.h5'
    start_feature = 4
    n_features, thresh = get_n_features_thresh(type, time_window)
    mask_value = 0
    series_len = 20
    epochs = 20
    batch_size = 256
    nclass = 2

    if train_again == 1:
        # Train
        print('loading training data...')
        X_train, y_train, nb_train = load_data(datafile=train_data_file,
                                               series_len=series_len,
                                               start_feature=start_feature,
                                               n_features=n_features,
                                               mask_value=mask_value,
                                               type=type,
                                               time_window=time_window)

        class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', classes=np.unique(y_train), y=y_train)
        class_weight_ = {0: class_weights[0], 1: class_weights[1]}
        print('done loading training data...')

        if type == 'gru':
            model = gru(n_features, series_len)
        elif type == 'lstm':
            model = lstm(n_features, series_len)
        print('training the model, wait until it is finished...')
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                      optimizer='RMSprop',
                      metrics=['accuracy'])

        history = model.fit(X_train,
                            y_train,
                            epochs=epochs,
                            batch_size=batch_size,
                            verbose=False,
                            shuffle=True,
                            class_weight=class_weight_)
        print('finished...')
        model.save(model_file)
        # Lime Feature Visualization""""""
        explainer = lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer(np.array(X_train.reshape(-1, 20*15)), mode='classification')
        # Select an instance from X_train for visualization
        instance = X_train[0]
        instance_reshaped = instance.reshape(1,-1)
        predict_fn = lambda x: model.predict(x)
        explanation = explainer.explain_instance(instance, predict_fn)

        # GradCam Model Visualization
        grad_cam = GradCAM(model=model, layer_name='attention_vector')
        image = X_train[0]  # Use an example input image
        image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
        image = tf.convert_to_tensor(image, dtype=tf.float32)
        heatmap = grad_cam.explain(image)
        print("Shape of X_train:", X_train.shape)
        print("Shape of discretized:", explainer.discretizer.discretized.shape)
        print("Shape of feature:", feature.shape)
    else:
        print('loading model...')
        model = load_model(model_file)
        print('done loading...')

    # Test
    print('loading testing data')
    X_test, y_test, nb_test = load_data(datafile=test_data_file,
                                        series_len=series_len,
                                        start_feature=start_feature,
                                        n_features=n_features,
                                        mask_value=mask_value,
                                        type=type,
                                        time_window=time_window)
    # Load the trained model
    model = load_model(model_file)
    """
    # Lime Feature Visualization
    explainer = lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer(X_test, mode='classification')
    # Select an instance from X_test for visualization
    instance = X_test[0]
    explanation = explainer.explain_instance(instance, model.predict_proba, num_features=n_features)

    # GradCam Model Visualization
    grad_cam = GradCAM(model=model, layer_name='attention_vector')
    image = X_test[0]  # Use an example input image
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    image = tf.convert_to_tensor(image, dtype=tf.float32)
    heatmap = grad_cam.explain(image)
    """
    print('done loading testing data...')
    print('predicting testing data...')
    prob = model.predict(X_test,
                         batch_size=batch_size,
                         verbose=False,
                         steps=None)
    print('done predicting...')
    print('writing prediction results into file...')
    output_result(test_data_file=test_data_file,
                  result_file=result_file,
                  type=type,
                  time_window=time_window,
                  start_feature=start_feature,
                  n_features=n_features,
                  thresh=thresh)
    print('done...')
```

When I run this command:
python newCMEpredict.py lstm 12 1

I get this error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joR0k.png)

> C:\Users\rayaa\Desktop\Summer Research\RNN-CME-prediction-main\CMEpredict>python newCMEpredict.py lstm 12 1
> Hello
> loading training data...
> done loading training data...
> training the model, wait until it is finished...
> finished...
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\rayaa\Desktop\Summer Research\RNN-CME-prediction-main\CMEpredict\newCMEpredict.py", line 302, in 
> explanation = explainer.explain_instance(instance, predict_fn)
> File "C:\Users\rayaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\lime\lime_tabular.py", line 340, in explain_instance
> data, inverse = self.__data_inverse(data_row, num_samples)
> File "C:\Users\rayaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\lime\lime_tabular.py", line 536, in __data_inverse
> first_row = self.discretizer.discretize(data_row)
> File "C:\Users\rayaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\lime\discretize.py", line 113, in discretize
> ret[:, feature]).astype(int)
> IndexError: index 15 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 15
>
> C:\Users\rayaa\Desktop\Summer Research\RNN-CME-prediction-main\CMEpredict>

Please help me troubleshoot as I have no clue how to fix these errors and correctly incorporate these technologies.

I have tried reshaping the array and changing the num_features parameter, to the point I even got rid of the parameter from the explainer.explain_instance line. I keep getting this error.